# How to get value from reference in c++

Tags: c++, boost, reference, boost-serialization

I have a func which returns a const& to an Object. Let say,

```
class Y {
    private:
        Id id;
    public:
        Id const& GetId() const;
}
```

Now this Y Object is part of another class, let say class X, which needs to be serialized by boost.

```
class X {
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, uint32 version)
     {
         ar & y->GetId();
     }
     Y y;
}
```

However, boost complains about this and gives error:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<x>'
```

```
C:\Users\Y.h(580) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator &<const Id>(T &)' being compiled
            with
            [
```

How can I serialize the Id?

Comment: Perhaps a review of the [Archive class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html) usage would be beneficial.

Comment: does `Id` have a `serialize` function?

Comment: Also can you post the entire compiler error message?

Comment: Yes. It does. Its part of a big chunk of code. But we do have logic to serialize Id. 
The compiler error is:
C:\Users\boost\windows\include\boost/archive/detail/check.hpp(162) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<x>'
        with
        [
            x=false
        ]
        C:\Users\boost\windows\include\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(577) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::check_const_loading<T>(void)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Id
        ]

Comment: The error message should contain a description of why the static assertion failed; what does it say? Does your real code incorrectly try to apply `->` to an object? Could we see the serialisation function for `Id`?

Comment: Id is just a typedef'd  string.
This is how it is serialized.

template <class Archive>                                       inline void serialize(Archive& ar,                          
                         Id& id,                     
                         uint32 version)                       
   {                                                           
      ar & static_cast<std::string&>(id);                      
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of boost serialization is to use references to serialize to an Archive.

Problem is it receives the values as references and not CONST references.

```
Id const& GetId() const; // Returns a const reference
```

Try using the following

```
Id & GetId();
```

And then one of the following

```
ar & y.GetId();
ar << y.GetId();
```

If you don't like the breaking of encapsulation then either use protected, friends, or copy it to another value and pass the value as reference

```
Id copy = y.GetId();
ar & copy;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 ar & y->GetId();
```

should be

```
  ar & y.GetId();
```

Comment: Agreed. I actually use a reference to object Y in my code. So it is ->
But for the given snippet it shud be y. instead of y->

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issue -> (see @thomas) you need to have two:

```
Id const& GetId() const;
Id& GetId();
```

Or you do BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER input/output into two.